# Why not simply use %h in OpenSSH ssh's ControlPath option?

Tags: ssh, openssh, connection-sharing

Why do the "ssh_config(5)" manpages recommend that the `ControlPath` option should contain at least the `%h`, `%p` and `%r` placeholders in order to **uniquely identify** each shared connection?

I thought that multiple sessions should **share** the same socket with a connection to the same host. Wouldn't it make sense then to have a simple definition such as:

```
ControlPath ~/.cache/ssh/mux/%h
```

Instead of something like:

```
ControlPath ~/.cache/ssh/mux/%r@%h:%p
```

In my understanding with the first definition one connection is shared between multiple sessions with different remote users, to the same remote host, on different remote ports.

I want to have the first defintion in the host default section so that it suffices to say `ssh -o ControlMaster=no`.

I want to share the connection to the same remote host between all sessions initiated by the same local user regardless of the remote user and remote port. The master client's socket should live beneath the local user's home directory.

Comment: *"I want to share the connection to the same remote host between all sessions initiated by the same local user regardless of the remote user and remote port."* Short answer: **you can't**.  I've added a sort of explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> "I thought that multiple sessions should share the same socket with a connection to the same host."

They can. However, note that if you connect to a host using an existing connection via `ControlPath`, regardless of which user you intend to log in as, you will be logged in as the original user of the connection.  Eg., with no established connection to "somewhere":

```
ssh -o ControlPath=~/.ssh/%h -o ControlMaster=yes bob@somewhere
```

This session is bob@somewhere.

```
ssh -o ControlPath=~/.ssh/%h -o ControlMaster=no sue@somewhere
```

This session will *also* be bob@somewhere, because you used the same ControlPath and set `ControlMaster=no`; if `ControlMaster=yes`, you'd be logged in as sue, but ssh will have ignored your ControlPath argument, as implied in `man ssh_config`:

> Additional sessions can connect to this socket *using the same ControlPath **with ControlMaster set to 'no'**.*

As evidence of this, if `ControlMaster=yes` in both cases, when bob exits the ControlPath socket `~/.ssh/somewhere` will disappear even though the "sue" session is still running, meaning *the sue session never used that socket*.

So, if you want to use the same connection, just `%h` is fine, but beware that **you cannot share a connection as multiple different remote users** -- ssh won't let you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Before your elaborate answer I missed the fact, that it's not possible to share a client's master socket between different remote users without at the same time the second remote user assuming the identity of the first one.

Answer (score 8):

You could have multiple users and multiple ports in use for even the same server.  Myself, I connect to hundreds of systems on the company's intranets, most have multiple users with different functions or app servers.  Access to userA is very different to access to userB, and the master connection would need to be different.  More succinctly, if you were to run:

```
$ ssh -n -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath=~/.cache/ssh/mux/%h -l userA localhost sleep 10 & # create the master connection and background it
$ ssh -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPath=~/.cache/ssh/mux/%h -l userB localhost whoami
userA
```

As you can see, we do not get an OpenSSH session with userB, but the original with userA.  That means that the home directory, permissions and even the authentication itself is not what is expected.  Using this, if you were to try to delete a file in userB's directory, then a) it could be the wrong file and b) it could be wrong permissions.

If you will *never* be connecting to more than a single user on any one server using a single port, then yes, using `%h` could be enough.  In your `~/.ssh/config` file, you would want to use:

```
ControlMaster=auto  # use existing or create a master connection
ControlPath=~/.cache/ssh/mux/%h
ControlPersist=yes
```

With the `ControlPersist` option, the master connection remains open in the background until killed or terminated with `ssh -O exit`.  This is a nice set-it-and-forget-it feature.

But if there is *any* possibility of connecting to more than one user on any one host, then you would want something more secure:

```
ControlMaster=auto
ControlPath=~/.cache/ssh/mux/%r@%h:%p
ControlPersist=yes
```

Comment: I'm still confused. I tried to clarify the configuration scenario and my intent in the "I want to" paragraphs. Could anyone of you answer my question more precisely with this additional info?